# How do I use a different query for a facet count

Tags: solr, solrj

Given a search for `q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=category` solr returns something like:

```
jackets (10)
shirts (5)
```

If I change the query to `q=name:shirt&facet=true&facet.field=category` then I get

```
jackets (0)
shirts (5)
```

I want to use a different query to generate the facets so it will count all facets not just those matching the query i.e. for a search of `"q=name:shirt"` it should return

```
jackets (10)
shirts (5)
```

I tried adding a facet.query parameter but it seems to have no effect. `facet.query=*:*` still returns

```
jackets (0)
shirts (5)
```

if I use a query of `q=name:shirt`

How do I use a different query to generate the facets? I'm using solr 5.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems facet.query is a facet query **within the query search results**. The solution is to use tags and exclusions e.g.

```
q={!tag=name}name&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=name}category
```

So for each query that I want to exclude I tag it and then reference it in the ex section of the facet.field

Although I'm starting to think that it may be better to use two queries and simply cache the facet results on the app server ...

Comment: You probably want to use fq-s to limit the result set after someone clicks a facet - they don't affect the score and can be cached separately (and provided without changing the users actual query). Using tags are the proper way of doing what you asked.